# Tabbar item title to multiline not displaying Swift 5 - Only Working with İPhone 11 series model

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have created custom `UITabBarController` class and set five `tabbar` items.
I want to set my last item which has `index item 4` title/label to multiline.

I have set it through code and added custom code for `item multiline text` but it is not working.

How can I fix this issue with iphone 8?

Update: its only working with iphone 11 series models but not with iphone 8 or iPhone SE (2nd generation).

my code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            
            let viewTabBar = items[4].value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
            
            print(viewTabBar?.subviews.count)
            if viewTabBar?.subviews.count == 2 {
                let label = viewTabBar?.subviews[1]as? UILabel
                label?.numberOfLines = 0
                label?.textAlignment = .center
                label?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                items[4].imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
               
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what does it mean "it is not working" ?

Comment: @zeytin tabbar title still showing on single line. I want to set it on two lines.